# Ruby paging over API response dataset causes memory spike

Tags: ruby, out-of-memory

I'm experiencing an issue with a large memory spike when I page through a dataset returned by an API. The API is returning ~150k records, I'm requesting 10k records at a time and paging through 15 pages of data. The data is an array of hashes, each hash containing 25 keys with ~50-character string values. This process kills my 512mb Heroku dyno.

I have a method used for paging an API response dataset.

```
def all_pages value_key = 'values', &block
  response = {}
  values = []
  current_page = 1
  total_pages = 1
  offset = 0

  begin
    response = yield offset

    #The following seems to be the culprit
    values += response[value_key] if response.key? value_key

    offset = response['offset']
    total_pages = (response['totalResults'].to_f / response['limit'].to_f).ceil if response.key? 'totalResults'
  end while (current_page += 1) <= total_pages

  values
end
```

I call this method as so:

```
all_pages("items") do |current_page|
  get "#{data_uri}/data", query: {offset: current_page, limit: 10000}
end
```

I know it's the concatenation of the arrays that is causing the issue as removing that line allows the process to run with no memory issues. What am I doing wrong? The whole dataset is probably no larger than 20mb - how is that consuming all the dyno memory? What can I do to improve the effeciency here?

**Update**

Response looks like this: `{"totalResults":208904,"offset":0,"count":1,"hasMore":true, limit:"10000","items":[...]}`

**Update 2**

Running with `report` shows the following:

```
[HTTParty] [2014-08-13 13:11:22 -0700] 200 "GET 29259/data" -
Memory 171072KB
[HTTParty] [2014-08-13 13:11:26 -0700] 200 "GET 29259/data" -
Memory 211960KB
  ... removed for brevity ...
[HTTParty] [2014-08-13 13:12:28 -0700] 200 "GET 29259/data" -
Memory 875760KB
[HTTParty] [2014-08-13 13:12:33 -0700] 200 "GET 29259/data" -
Errno::ENOMEM: Cannot allocate memory - ps ax -o pid,rss | grep -E "^[[:space:]]*23137"
```

**Update 3**

I can recreate the issue with the basic script below. The script is hard coded to only pull 100k records and already consumes over 512MB of memory on my local VM.

```
#! /usr/bin/ruby
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'
require 'json'

uri = URI.parse("https://someapi.com/data")
offset = 0
values = []

begin
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  http.use_ssl = true
  http.set_debug_output($stdout)

  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri + "?limit=10000&offset=#{offset}")
  request.add_field("Content-Type", "application/json")
  request.add_field("Accept", "application/json")

  response = http.request(request)
  json_response = JSON.parse(response.body)

  values << json_response['items']
  offset += 10000

end while offset < 100_000

values
```

**Update 4**

I've made a couple of improvements which seem to help but not completely alleviate the issue.

1) Using `symbolize_keys` turned out to consume less memory. This is because the keys of each hash are the same and it's cheaper to symbolize them then to parse them as seperate Strings.

2) Switching to `ruby-yajl` for JSON parsing consumes significantly less memory as well.

Memory consumption of processing 200k records:

`JSON.parse(response.body)`: 861080KB (Before completely running out of memory)

`JSON.parse(response.body, symbolize_keys: true)`: 573580KB

`Yajl::Parser.parse(response.body)`: 357236KB

`Yajl::Parser.parse(response.body, symbolize_keys: true)`: 264576KB

This is still an issue though.

- Why does a dataset that's no more than 20MB take that much memory to process?
- What is the "right way" to process large datasets like this?
- What does one do when the dataset becomes 10x larger? 100x larger?

I will buy a beer for anyone who can thoroughly answer these three questions!

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You check `current_page` against `total_pages` which might even be not defined. Would you mind to post `response` here? Does it contain `limit` key?

Comment: Response doesn't have a limit key and I don't think it's related as the issue goes away if you don't add the new response values into `values`.

Comment: Whether response doesn’t have a `limit` key, what `response['limit']` is about? The issue looks like to be induced (e.g. you iterate more times than you expected.) Aha, after taking a look at the `response` you’ve posted: would you mind to calc `total_pages` so that it does not go to `INF`? I suggest you to pass limit to block as well and loop `while (current_page += limit)`.

Comment: I'm watching the console and seeing the logs of the requests. It's definitely not going past the 15 pages it needs.

Comment: You divide by `nil` in your code and you appeal to the fact logs show everything is OK? I put my hands in my pockets.

Comment: My apologies, turns out posting at 3am doesn't help with comprehension. `response` does have a limit key, it get's inserted after-the-fact by the `get` method. I have updated the post to include this. However, I'm pretty confident the paging is working correctly and not going on infinitely. Is there anything you can spot about the array methods that can cause the memory issue?

Comment: Unfortunately I can’t say anything w/out additional benchmarks. Would you mind to define `def report ; puts 'Memory ' + \`ps ax -o pid,rss | grep -E "^[[:space:]]*#{$$}"\`.strip.split.map(&:to_i)[1].to_s + 'KB' ; end` and put `report` right after your calls to `array += ...`? There might be a need to try with and without `ObjectSpace.garbage_collect`.

Comment: I've updated the post with the results. Before I tried explicitly calling `GC.start` before each concat to no avail. How would I go about testing with `ObjectSpace.garbage_collect`?

Comment: I ran into the [possibly same] issue last year: http://rocket-science.ru/hacking/2013/12/17/ruby-memory-pitfalls/ On the other hand, it looks like your data _should not_ increase internal ruby heaps. Please print out the memory reports on your own machine (I am curious whether ruby releases the memory at all,) and try to put `ObjectSpace.garbage_collect` right after `JSON.parse`.

Comment: @mudasobwa - Calling `ObjectSpace.garbage_collect` after the parsing doesn't seem to have any effect on the memory consumption. I read your blog post but I'm thinking that my issue is different because the problem is not that the OS doesn't get the memory back but that Ruby runs out of memory. If there were free heaps available - Ruby would use those - correct? (Thanks for all your help thus far.)

Comment: Well, you are welcome. It’s interesting and I like puzzles. Would you mind to give me an access to your real data (ftp or like to zipped file) if it does not contain any private info? I would try to play with it here, just because that’s a type of question which is challenging to have an answer to (and because I like the free beer, of course :).)

Answer (score 0):

You've identified the problem to be using `+=` with your array. So the likely solution is to add the data without creating a new array each time.

`values.push response[value_key] if response.key? value_key`

Or use the `<<`

`values << response[value_key] if response.key? value_key`

You should only use `+=` if you actually want a new array. It doesn't appear you do actually want a new array, but actually just want all the elements in a single array.

Comment: I've tried `push` and `concat` without any luck. I'll try `<<` and report back. Thanks!

Comment: Nope - still seeing the same thing using `<<`.