# Ruby combining two arrays causes process to run out of memory

Tags: ruby, arrays, out-of-memory, ruby-2.1

Combining two arrays of hashes that have 100k items each causes a process running on a 2GB VM to run out of memory. I'm failing to understand how/why.

Let's say I have a Hash like this and I populate it with 50 key/value pairs.

```
h = {}
1..50.times{ h[SecureRandom.hex] = SecureRandom.hex}
```

I place 100k `h`s into two Arrays as so:

```
a = []
a1 = []
1..100_000.times{ a << h }
1..100_000.times{ a1 << h }
```

When I try to add `a1` into `a`, IRB runs out of memory:

```
2.1.1 :008 > a << a1
NoMemoryError: failed to allocate memory
```

Are the two arrays really too big to combine in memory? What is the preferred way to accomplish this?

I'm running `ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-linux]` and the VM has no other processes running on it.

Comment: 100k items? more like 5,000,000 items each. 50 * 100,000 = 5 million. joining them would then produce a 10 million item array.

Comment: I show it using 1.72G of Real Memory, 4.87G virtual on Ruby 2.1.2 on OSX. So yeah totally possible it is running out of ram..

Comment: Runs fine for me. It's worth noting that those lists have 100K references to the same hash. `a << a1` also adds a reference to `a1` to the end. Maybe you want `a += a1`.

Comment: It shouldn't. Especially since `a << a1` isn't really copying anything other than a reference to a1. I suspect what's really happening is that IRB is running out of memory while trying to display the resulting array.

Comment: I might be missing somethign but - the hash is populated with random key/value pairs fifty times and then the hash is added to each array 100k times making for two arrays with 100k items each where each item is a hash with 50 k/v pairs. No?

Comment: You are correct. However, each item isn't just *a* hash with 50 k/v pairs, it's the *same* hash. So probably using a lot less memory than you would expect.

Comment: @tadman a += a1 causes the same thing.

Comment: @Ajedi32 and @tadman wouldn't a reference to same hash use less memory rather than more memory? Furthermore, changing it so ` 1..100_000.times{ a << h.clone }` causes the same issue. Can you tell me what your memory usage is when it's running? Thanks!

Comment: @user1032752 Yes, references do use less memory. I said that in my comment. Try adding a semicolon after your final statement, to tell IRB not to display the result.

Comment: @Ajedi32 - I think you're right with IRB not being able to display the output. Running `a += a1; nil` completes instantly with no memory spike. You want to submit an answer for that?

Comment: @user1032752 Will do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is most likely not that Ruby is running out of memory while performing this operation (especially since there's only one copy of the `h` hash), but rather that IRB is running out of memory while trying to display the result. Try adding a `; nil` after the final line in IRB; that should solve the problem since it will prevent IRB from trying to display the result hash.

Example:

```
require 'securerandom'
require 'objspace'

h = {}
1..50.times{ h[SecureRandom.hex] = SecureRandom.hex}
a = []
a1 = []
1..100_000.times{ a << h }
1..100_000.times{ a1 << h }
a << a1; nil # Semicolon and nil are for IRB, not needed with regular Ruby

puts "Total memory usage: #{ObjectSpace.memsize_of_all/1000.0} KB"
```

I get a result of `Total memory usage: 7526.543 KB`; no where close to 2 GB.

Comment: Thanks again, I asked this while troulbeshooting this question - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25278660/ruby-paging-over-api-response-dataset-causes-memory-spike) - think you can help at all?

Comment: It could be that rendering out the list itself as a string is causing the memory failure.

Comment: @tadman Could be. Honestly though I'm not sure. All I can do is point you to [ObjectSpace](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/objspace/rdoc/ObjectSpace.html#method-c-memsize_of) as a potential resource for debugging.

Comment: The array itself is pretty compact, it's just references, but expanding that to a string with `inspect` could be very painful.